# How to pass full device info from CSV file in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have added full device information in CSV file and here device information:

```
{"IpAddress":"fec0::15:b2ff:fe00:0fec0::ac6b:8271:fa94:818c192.168.232.2fec0::10bf:85ff:fe05:9ec1fec0::a1f6:b9e4:fd47:4b15192.168.200.2","BuildVersion":"1.0","DeviceManufacturer":"Google","DeviceOS":"android","DeviceVersion":"28","IMEINumber":"358240051111110","NetworkCountryISO":"us","PhoneNumber":"","SIMCountryISO":"us","SIMSerialID":"89014103211118510720","SIMState":"5","UUIDNumber":"eda5b585a146e41d"}
```

which I passed in a CSV and when I run this code every time it's give me error because full device info is not passing. Please help me how to solve this issue.

Thank You.

Comment: Try saving the JSON body in a text file and pass it using : **${__FileToString(${__eval(D:\jsonFile)}.txt,,)}**

Answer (score 0):

CSV stands for [comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and there are 11 commas in your "full device info" so the options are in:

1. Change the "delimiter" in the [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to some character which is not present in your test data, for example `|`

   [image]
2. Use [__StringFromFile() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) which reads the next line from the file each time it's being called directly in the relevant [Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers)

   [image]

Comment: Thank You for your information and I will try this steps on my project.